# Dojo/AMD module ID case sensitivity

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I'm working with some dojo code and I found what I think are 2 modules with similar names:

```
foo/blarg
foo/Blarg
```

Does Dojo/AMD allow module ids to differ only by case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be possible but files for the module must have the same case as the identification in the require.

Example:

```
blarg.js
Blarg.js
```

I would also suggest you use a good naming for the module in case you have no strong naming convention in place. Example using require:

```
require(['foo/blarg', 'foo/Blarg' ], function(blarg, Blarg){});
```

Comment: For future seekers: While AMD module ids can differ by only casing, my build was missing files because I was running it on a Mac, which is case insensitive by default.